# aframe environment component with particle system

Tags: aframe, webvr

I was trying to add different particles from particle component in combination with environment component of aframe, i was not able to create a fiddle as at the time of writing this question i was getting 'Not found: package "aframe-environment-component" ' for [aframe-environment-component](https://unpkg.com/aframe-environment-component/dist/aframe-environment-component.min.js),
 While looking around i found  [takahirox](https://cdn.rawgit.com/takahirox/aframe-rain/v1.0.2/index.html), which works well with environment component (tested), but i am trying to put different particle system effect to different environments. I tried to set presets for different particle systems like, rain, snow, etc. But, i was not able to run it successfully with environment-component and particle system component in one page, if i remove environment component, i am able to set particle system properly, but not with environment component. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am quite unable to figure out why they are not working together, so I can only offer a workaround: You can tweak takahirox component properties to get snow, I've tried setting:

`color:#ffffff;vector:-1 -2 0;count:500;opacity: 1;splash:false;width:40;dropHeight:0.2`

 White color, slower drop, less drops, no opacity, no splash, no "rainDrop tail", and it quite looks like [snow](https://jsfiddle.net/odk2ktpn/4/) :)
If You want to achieve dust, i would get there a brown fog, and make the rain go more horizontal ( tweak the vector attribute ).

Comment: Thanks @Adam, this is not exactly what i want but its almost near to what i was trying to achieve. and this one works perfectly with aframe environment component.